# Why Docker resets connection upon pushing an image to a private registry?

Tags: jenkins, docker, docker-registry

We have a Docker private registry, listening on a non-default port (specified in our `docker run` command). However, our attempts to push an image (either pre-built, or built via Jenkins) fail with an error message (see bold below). Help at your earliest convenience will be much appreciated.

We simply installed Docker on the machine and started the registry as follows:

`docker run -d -p 9010:9010 --restart=always --name registry registry:2`

Then we tried to test our registry per Docker's documentation, as follows:

`docker pull ubuntu && docker tag ubuntu localhost:9010/ubuntu
docker push localhost:9010/ubuntu`

**Error:**

`The push refers to a repository [localhost:9010/ubuntu]
Put http://localhost:9010/v1/repositories/ubuntu/: read tcp [::1]:37399->[::1]:9010: read: connection reset by peer`

**Jenkins error:**

`[workspace] $ docker push HOSTNAME:9010/registry:2
The push refers to a repository [HOSTNAME:9010/registry]
unable to ping registry endpoint https://HOSTNAME:9010/v0/
v2 ping attempt failed with error: Get https://HOSTNAME:9010/v2/: dial tcp IP_ADDRESS:9010: getsockopt: connection refused
v1 ping attempt failed with error: Get https://HOSTNAME:9010/v1/_ping: dial tcp IP_ADDRESS:9010: getsockopt: connection refused`

Answer (score 2):

You have to trust the remote repo in the docker config

I think the file is found at /etc/default/docker

You need to do DOCKER_OPTS --insecure-registry

Google that and you will find the line you need to add

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Actually, we have used the `--insecure-registry` option initially, but later moved on to using self-signed certificates, as described here: https://github.com/docker/distribution/blob/master/docs/insecure.md. Perhaps, our certificate configuration is messed up. Sorry about not mentioning in the question of our switch to a more secure option.

Comment: Just confirmed with my colleague that we have been seeing the same error when using the `--insecure-registry` option as well.

Answer (score 2):

This how it works for me :

```
DOCKER_OPTS="--insecure-registry myserver.com:5000"
```

Comment: Thank you for your help (+1). Please see my comments below. I'm not working on this right now, but will investigate further, when return to it.